# CakePHP 3: add extra field to access from template

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm using `CakePHP 3.6`

I have two models `Users` and `WalletTransactions`.

`WalletTransactions` is associated with `Users` with `user_id` and have a column `price`.

I am using following code to show the list of users

**UsersController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = $this->Users->find();

    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

**users/index.ctp**

```
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>

    <?= $user->name ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, I want to show the sum of `price` from `WalletTransactions` inside the list of users in the template.

For that, I have written a function to get the sum of `price` in `WalletTransactionsTable.php`

```
public function walletBalance($user_id)
{
    $total_balance = 0;

    $walletTransactions = $this->find()
        ->where([
            'user_id' => $user_id
        ]);

    foreach ($walletTransactions as $transaction) {
        $total_balance += $transaction->price;
    }

    return $total_balance;
}
```

and set a property function in `User.php` entity class

```
protected function _balance()
{
    $user_id = $this->_properties['id'];

    $WalletTransactions = TableRegistry::get('WalletTransactions');

    $transaction = $WalletTransactions->walletBalance($user_id);

    return $transaction;
}
```

in the template in the `users` loop when using

```
<?= $user->balance ?>
```

it prints nothing.

**How can I show values from other models inside a template?**

Comment: The name of the function inside User Entity should be _getBalance() and not _balance()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessors must start with `_get`, ie `_getBalance`. However, ideally entities should be stupid data containers, making them issue queries isn't the best idea, not to mention that it's rather inefficient to issue a query everytime a property is being accessed.

I'd suggest to use for example a custom finder. Also there's no need to retrieve all transactions and calculate on PHP level, this can be easily done on SQL level instead:

```
// UsersTable

public function findWithWalletBalance(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->leftJoinWith($this->WalletTransactions->getName())
        ->select([
            'balance' => $query->func()->sum($this->WalletTransactions->aliasField('price'))
        ])
        ->group(array_map([$this, 'aliasField'], (array)$this->getPrimaryKey()))
        ->enableAutoFields(true);
}
```

```
// UsersController

public function index()
{
    $users = $this->Users->find('withWalletBalance');

    $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Entities > Accessors & Mutators](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using leftJoinWith](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-leftjoinwith)**